# Might you ever have had read . . .?

Tags: grammar

> Might you ever have had read that book?

Can you use something like this, in English?

Comment: *might have had read* is impossible: what you want is merely *might have read* (the tensed modal *might* takes a following infinitive, that infinitive perfect *have* takes a following past participle *read*).

Comment: I see. I thank you, StoneyB. Why may *might*, I guess, passed of *may*, maybe, utilize an infinitive, and not a passed, like had(?), too? And, may, I guess *might [you] [ever] have read [that book] [?]* mean they may, or may not, have read it, if they have, they still might? What if they, maybe, have read some, and may not read it, now? May *have* not mean they still do?

Comment: Modal verbs (can/could,may/might,must,shall/should,will/would) always take an infinitive complement. The distinctions between 'past' and 'present' forms of the modal verbs are very complicated and unpredictable; over the past three centuries they have been slowly evolving into essentially distinct words, but except with *must* (which is historically the past form of the now vanished *mote*) the evolution is not yet complete.

Comment: I greatly appreciate it, StoneyB. So, I thought *might* seemed passed, of *may*. I think, I read it used like this, "1) MAY / MIGHT Present: When he is at school, he may not go to the bathroom without asking for permission. Past: When he was at school, he might not go to the bathroom without asking for permission.” It seemed to use one passed, and one not. So, I guess, I, maybe, may not get why might may, I think you stated, utilize *have*. May that (*have*) assume, in this interrogative, that they maybe did, and still do, read that book?

Comment: *Might* is indeed the past form of *may*; but it doesn't always indicate past tense. It may indicate 'modal remoteness' (nonfactuality) or 'social remoteness' (politeness, non-demand), which I think is the case in your example. When it is used in one of these senses the perfect construction (*have* + past participle) is employed to mark past tense.

Comment: Remoteness. Gripping. I guess, from what I read, *might*, and *may* may have different senses. In some senses, *may* may utilize a passed verb(?). In remoteness, it may use a “perfect construction”. I may seem new to “infinitive compliment”, and “perfect construction”. I may try to read upon these. I guess, one thing I thought, I thought that *have* may assume, in an interrogative, that they maybe did, and still do, read that book. So, I guess, I felt not sure about it . . .

Answer (score 2):

*Might you ever have read* is OK. It's asking if they already read it in the past (NOT still reading it). *Might you ever had read* and *Might you ever have had read* are both ungrammatical. If you need to know if they were in the process of still reading it, you could ask: "Might you have been reading that book when you fell asleep?" Or: "Might you ever have been reading that book when you would fall asleep?"